# How to specify datum for avro union type without ambiguity?

Tags: python, avro

I am writing a python program using the official avro library for python, version 1.8.2.

This is a simple schema to show my problem:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.example",
  "name": "NameUnion",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": [
        {
          "type": "record",
          "namespace": "com.example",
          "name": "FullName",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "first",
              "type": "string"
            },
            {
              "name": "last",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "record",
          "namespace": "com.example",
          "name": "ConcatenatedFullName",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "entireName",
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Possible datums for this schema would be `{"name": {"first": "Hakuna", "last": "Matata"}}` and `{"name": {"entireName": "Hakuna Matata"}}`.

However, this gives margin to ambiguity, as not always avro will be able to detect the right schema specified in the union. In this case, either datum will correspond to 1 and only 1 valid schema, but there might be a case where more than 1 schema in the union would be valid.

I wonder whether it would be possible to use a datum like `{"name": {"FullName": {"first": "Hakuna", "last": "Matata"}}}`, where the specific union schema name is specified in the datum.

Is it possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

After researching a lot, I found out that the representation that contains information about the types is the [Avro JSON encoding standard](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#json_encoding).

This unfortunately is not supported by either the official python library nor by fastavro, at the date I am writing this text.